# apt- “Unable to locate package” error in Ubuntu 18.04 on Mac when trying to set up VPS

Tags: apt, server, software-installation, proxy

I was trying to set up and connect to my Google Cloud VPS using this tutorial on [Set Up Your own Google Cloud Proxy Servers | BlackHatWorld](https://www.blackhatworld.com/seo/set-up-your-own-google-cloud-proxy-servers.1057000/).

Then at a point when I had to install my proxy server, I encountered this

```
apt-get install <username>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package <username>
```

I googled and have updated/upgraded `sudo` as some suggested, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no indeed any package like `<username>`. As I can see [there](https://www.blackhatworld.com/seo/set-up-your-own-google-cloud-proxy-servers.1057000/), the confusion arose just because user they added had the similar name as of package. Package name is still `squid`. Install that using:

```
sudo apt install squid
```